# Disable a Javascript to overcome an error (Chrome)

Tags: javascript

I have a .json extension in Chrome that my friend created and its function is to auto-populate all the fields in the form based on what I choose on a drop down but until yesterday, when I choose an option in the dropdown, it will auto-populate all the fields once then the browser will restart with an error that I need to enter first the one with asterisks (*) and all the data it populates will be gone. After checking in the browser, I notice that a new line has been added and I guess this is the cause of the error.

```
<!--
document.main.FIRST_NAME.onblur=validateForm;
document.main.LAST_NAME.onblur=validateForm;
-->
```

This is what my .json extension looks like:

```
function XXXX() {
    document.getElementById('postalCode').value="XXXX";
    document.getElementById('postOfficeBox').value="XXXX";
    document.getElementById('co').value="XXXX";
    document.getElementById('description').value="XXXX";
    document.getElementById('street').value="XXXX";
    document.getElementById('st').value="";
    document.getElementById('roomNumber').value="XXXX";

    var username = document.getElementById('USER_ID');
    var email = document.getElementById('EMAIL');

    username.addEventListener("blur", function(){
        email.value = username.value + "@XXXX.com";
    });
}

var region = document.getElementById("physicalDeliveryOfficeName");
region.addEventListener('change', function(){
    if (region.value == "XXXX") {
        XXXX();
}
}
```

I'm trying to fix this since yesterday but I can't seem to overcome it. I have an experience in programming but it's my first time to use Javascript. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: *"the browser will restart"* Are you sure about that? Maybe you mean that the page reloads? Please read [mcve].

Comment: @FelixKling yes it will reload. Sorry for the confusion.